# How do I fix "Error-[IBLHS-NT] Illegal behavioral left hand side"?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to debug this code shown below. I can not get it to work at all. The attached Verilog file has two modues: 1)  "equality" which defines the Device Under Test (DUT) and 2) "test" which generates the inputs to test the DUT. The module "equality" has a coding error.  Let me know if you can give me a hint. Thanks!

The errors I am receiving are:

```
Error-[IBLHS-NT] Illegal behavioral left hand side
ECE413/src/Equality_bugs_Test_Bench.v, 7
  Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment.
  The offending expression is : Equal
  Source info: Equal = 1;

Error-[IBLHS-NT] Illegal behavioral left hand side
ECE413/src/Equality_bugs_Test_Bench.v, 9
  Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment.
  The offending expression is : Equal
  Source info: Equal = 0;
```

My SystemVerilog Code is:

```
module equality (Equal, a, b); // This module defines the DUT.
 input[3:0] a, b;
 output Equal;
 always @ (a or b)
   begin
      if (a == b)
         Equal = 1;
      else
         Equal = 0;
    end
endmodule
//
//
//
module test; // This is the test bench. It specifies input signals to drive the DUT.

 reg [3:0] a, b;
 wire Equal;

equality Eq1 (Equal, a, b); // This line instantiates the DUT.

initial 
  begin
     a = 4'b0000; // Initialize "a" to 0.
     b = 4'b0000; // Initialize "b" to 0.
     #512 $finish; // Simulate for 32x16 = 512 time steps to exercise the entire truth table.
          // (32 steps/cycle x 16 cycles)

  end

// The next four lines clock the bits of input "b" so as to count up from 0 to 15.
  always  #2 b[0] = ~b[0]; // (Note: all procedural blocks run concurrently.)
  always  #4 b[1] = ~b[1]; 
  always  #8 b[2] = ~b[2];
  always #16 b[3] = ~b[3]; // One complete cycle is 2x16 = 32 time steps.

  always #32 a = a+1; // "a" is incremented by one after each complete count of "b".  

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procedural assignments (inside `always` blocks) must be made to signals declared as `reg`.  Change:

```
 output Equal;
```

to:

```
 output reg Equal;
```

For a shorter, equivalent version:

```
module equality (
    output Equal,
    input [3:0] a, b
);
    assign Equal = (a == b);
endmodule
```